# Ubuntu is acting weird since Stacer operation

Tags: read-only

I have Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and everything was fine until I used Stacer's "System Cleaner" function. I selected "All" that means package caches, crash reports, application logs, application caches and trash. Then I hit the "cleanup" button (which I assume means delete).

Since then the system has been doing strange things. For example, on startup, it goes to BusyBox and I have to `fsck -yf /dev/sda2` practically every time.

I cannot create a folder on the desktop. I get "The destination is read only"

Additionally, Firefox won't start. It says "Firefox is already running" but there's no process called Firefox running and I cannot delete the lock file in the `~/.mozilla/firefox` directory because it says "cannot remove lock: read-only file system" and If I try changing the permissions on the lock file using `chmod 777` it says "cannot operate on dangling symlink"

Synaptic Package Manager also wont start. "Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend"

Also, it seems to do a "screen refresh" (my words) every 30 seconds or so and it puts the mouse cursor back in the right bottom corner.

Other weirdness includes being able to open Pinta but not close it.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: this command helped greatly:

```
sudo mount -oremount,rw /
```

which remounts the file system as read/write. Since issuing that command, Firefox, Synaptic etc are working. But I am still getting the "screen refresh/freeze" every 30 seconds or so.

Comment: Is there a log of all of the actions this software performed?  There are so many problems from the use of this software, you probably shouldn't use it again. It seems you have to provide the software an outrageous level of permissions and allow it to plow through every aspect of your system.  All for what benefit exactly?  I would not touch software like this with a 10 ft pole especially since it's not in Ubuntu repos and seems like it hasn't been maintained since 2019.

Comment: @Nmath It is in the Universe repository and I've tested in many machines over several releases with zero problems. This points to a different problem, likely a user induced deep issue with the software sources and/or file system errors, etc.

Comment: @Nmath Just used it right now, it deleted ~1.5GB of package caches, other caches, logs and trash. Everything is perfectly fine.